# JS can't enable the button after disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

**JS**

I have a form which has save and download button.I want the download button to be disabled initially.when the form is saved it should be enabled.

```js
$("#download_form").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   $('.save-form').on('click', function(){
   $("#download_form").removeAttr('disabled');
 });
```

```html
 .fieldset
          .row
            .col-sm-3
              = f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary save-form"
            .col-sm-3
              = f.submit "cancel", type: :reset, class: "btn btn-primary"
            .col-sm-3
              %div{id: 'download_form'}
              - if @customer_detail.save
                = link_to "Download", download_csv_customer_detail_path(@customer_detail.id, format: "csv"), disabled: true, class: "btn btn-primary"
            .col-sm-3
              = link_to("Print", "javascript:print()", class: "btn btn-primary")
```

The problem is i can't able to enable back the download button after the form is saved.can someone plz help me.thanks in advance!!

Comment: `$("#download_form").prop('disabled', true);
$("#download_form").prop('disabled', false);` use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: If the element to be clicked is appended dynamically, you need to use event delegation to make the `click` work.

Comment: I've tried that.but still got the same problem

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tw90pfpg/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Form submit event of the form.

```
$("#download_form").submit(function(){
    $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `prop` method to do this. And apply the value as `true` or `false`.

**Disable**

```
$("#download_form").prop('disabled', true);
```

**Enable**

```
$("#download_form").prop('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <form>
  <button id="save">Save</button>
  <button id="download" disabled>Download</button>
 </form>

 $('#save').on('click', function() {
    $("#download").attr('disabled', false);
  });
```